# How to stop new members created by admins using Profile:Edit from going into the Pending group

Tags: members, profile-edit

I'm using Profile:Edit to create new member accounts on the front-end. I've got my member preferences set to 'Manual activation by an administrator.'

When creating a new member account (by a Super Admin, or a 'client admin' member account that has permissions to create new members), I'm finding that new member accounts are still going into the Pending queue.

Is there a way to make accounts created by an admin go into the proper member group that I've specified? This is adding an extra step to the process of creating new members. I'd rather not change the activation preference to 'No activation required' as we do still want to approve new member accounts that are created on the front end of the site by guests; but I would have thought/hoped that EE or Profile:Edit would smart enough (unless I'm doing something wrong) to realise that if an admin is creating the new member account, it doesn't need to go into the Pending group. Any advice or workarounds would be appreciated, thanks.

Here's the simplified code from my new member registration form for Profile:Edit:

```
{exp:profile:register include_jquery="no" datepicker="no" return="/extranet" dynamic_screen_name="[cf_profile_first_name] [cf_profile_last_name]" group_id="10"}

  <p><label>First name <em>*</em></label></p>
  <p><input class="required" name="cf_profile_first_name" placeholder="First Name" type="text" value="{cf_profile_first_name}" /></p>

  <p><label>Last name <em>*</em></label></p>
  <p><input class="required" name="cf_profile_last_name" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" value="{cf_profile_last_name}" /></p>

  <p><label>Email <em>*</em></label></p>
  <p><input class="required" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text" value="{email}" /></p>

  <p><label>Password <em>*</em></label></p>
  <p><input class="required" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" value="" />

<input type="submit" value="Create new login &raquo;" />

{/exp:profile:register}
```

Comment: I believe the Manual Activation setting for new members is what dictates the Pending members, not Profile:Edit. Does using the specific set member group id tag within the registration form help at all?

Comment: Hi Jessica, thanks for your comment. I'm using the specific group_id in the example above but it still sets them to the Pending group (then they go to the correct group once activated). I've also tried using the exp:profile:member_group_select tag instead of the group_id parameter, but to no avail. Given that you say it's the manual activation that dictates this, I'll have a think and see if I can fit around this with my workflow, thanks. Also, feel free to add that as an answer and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at your code, you aren't telling Profile:Edit what member group to place the new user, so it's using the default. Based on the [Profile:Edit documentation](http://mightybigrobot.com/docs/profile-edit/#member-group-select) your code should include an admin visible ONLY: member group drop down menu.

```
{if logged_in}
    {exp:profile:register}

        {exp:profile:member_group_select member_groups="5|6|7"}

    {/exp:profile:register}
{/if}
```

So based on your form data, you'd need to modify, something like this…

```
{exp:profile:register include_jquery="no" datepicker="no" return="/extranet" dynamic_screen_name="[cf_profile_first_name] [cf_profile_last_name]" group_id="10"}

  <p><label>First name <em>*</em></label></p>
  <p><input class="required" name="cf_profile_first_name" placeholder="First Name" type="text" value="{cf_profile_first_name}" /></p>

  <p><label>Last name <em>*</em></label></p>
  <p><input class="required" name="cf_profile_last_name" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" value="{cf_profile_last_name}" /></p>

  <p><label>Email <em>*</em></label></p>
  <p><input class="required" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text" value="{email}" /></p>

  <p><label>Password <em>*</em></label></p>
  <p><input class="required" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" value="" />

{if logged_in}

        {exp:profile:member_group_select member_groups="5|6|7"}

{/if}

<input type="submit" value="Create new login &raquo;" />

{/exp:profile:register}
```

Obviously, specify your member groups, instead of the default, but that should do the placement.

Answer (score 1):

As Jessica noted, "Require Member Account Activation?" is an EE config setting (available in the CP Member module) that Profile:Edit is simply echoing in its own settings. Unless you change this setting to "No Activation Required" then the new registered user will go into Pending group if you are registering them with a Profile:Edit register tag.

To get around it, you'd need to hook into P:E or the Member module and make some changes.